# Script add's md5sum to duplicate filenames but still get error notifications when executed

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, hashsum

So by using some info from other threads on this site I have managed to get a script to copy files to another directory, then add the md5sum into the duplicate file names. However, I'm not fully satisfied as I'm still receiving a couple of BASH notifications when I execute the script which I could do with some help understanding/resolving. Firstly here is the script.

```
cp -r $dir1/* $dir2

cd $dir2  

fdupes -r $dir2 | while read i; do

bn="${i%.*}"
ext="${i##*.}"
md5=$(md5sum "$i" | awk '{ print $1 }')

mv -v "$i" "${bn}_${md5}.${ext}"

done
```

The messages I am receiving when the script is run are:

```
md5sum: : No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘’: No such file or directory
```

As I say, the script does seem to work, but any ideas on why I receiving these messages would be appreciated, as would any suggestion to tweak/improve the script. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, i guess there is an issue with `fdupes` command which output an empty line at the end :

```
[PRD][]localhost:~ 12:17:09     
$ fdupes -r work/
work/sockperf-sockperf_v2/news          
work/sockperf-sockperf_v2/src/.dirstamp
work/sockperf-sockperf_v2/src/.deps/.dirstamp

[PRD][]localhost:~ 12:17:19
```

Then while processing in the loop, the last element is empty which produces an error in `md5sum` like when file is nonexistant :

```
$ md5sum ' ' 
md5sum: : no such file of directory
```

And then the script tries to move this empty name file which produces also the `mv` error.

Comment: Immediately below the `while read i; do`, add this line `test -z "$i" && continue`

Comment: roaima- thanks that worked a treat :)))) Don't suppose you could explain why that worked and your logic could you? No worries if not, you've already helped me lots.

Comment: `test -z $i` will test if Variable `i` is empty. If not the `&& continue` will continue to loop into the `while`. Don't forget to accept the answer if you are happy with the outcome.

Comment: thanks netmonk, that makes your original answer more understandable to a noob like me, cheers. I've accepted the original answer now I understanding it more.